# VS2010 'Show Derived Types' option missing in Class View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working with a Visual C# project in Visual Studio 2010 and browsing various types in the Class View. According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy6s2t6h.aspx) documentation, there is supposed to be a 'Show Derived Types' option in the class view settings menu similar to the 'Show Base Types' option. However, it seems to be missing.

I haven't managed to find any bug reports or references to this issue so I'm wondering if I'm just missing something here.

Comment: I'd really like to know how to get it to show too

Comment: FYI, this is also affecting VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I see it in Visual Studio 2010, a C++ project with derived types. However, in a C# project as mentioned with derived types, this option is not provided. I am checking on a project without derived types to see if that may be a cause for the option to be disabled.

**EDIT:** It appears that a project without derived types do not seem to disable the option, but I can only see the option on C++ projects, and not for Visual C# projects.

**C++ Project with derived types** (opened in the [Visual C++ Dev Environment Setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384847.aspx)):

[image: Class View]

[image: C++ Class View Options]

**C# Project with derived types**, note that this solution is opened in the [Visual C# Development Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173063.aspx)

[image]

My **assumption** is that the documentation listed is for specific environments and project types only.

Answer (score 0):

After asking the ukMSDN twitter account I got the following response, hope it helps:

> This menu option is only available in
>   the Class Designer, not in UML Class
>   diagrams - hope that helps :)

Comment: As far as I know, I'm using neither the Class Designer nor a UML class diagram. Maybe they didn't understand the question?